# split an array into multiple part based on key pattern

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

i have a single array that i wish to split up into multiple arrays based on the keys within the array.

so in example below there are 3 keys: 1.post, 2.social,3,test. i want to be able to end up with three separate arrays

my question is that i want to split them into three separate arrays. what is the best way to do this. the closest function i found is **array_chunk** however this splits the array into a defined size- i don'
t know the potential size of the array

:

```
array
  'post-postcode' => string 'tb44 24BQ' (length=9)
  'post-telephone' => string '0208  2414399' (length=13)
  'social-linkedin' => string 'linkedin-Waters' (length=15)
  'test-testi' => string '6' (length=1)
  'test-name' => string 'Rodgers Castro' (length=14)
```

Comment: and what is your question? also show your current code.

Comment: Your example contains five keys, not three.

Comment: hi justBaron- yes, five keys taht will be split into 3 seperate array. i.e 'post' will form an array with 2 keys: kesy post-postcode and post-telephone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly you can do it like the following, but it is an XY problem, why are you not structuring your arrays properly first?

```
$normalised = [];
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    list($k, $a) = explode('-', $key, 2);
    $normalised[$k][$a] = $value;
}
```

Comment: hi Lawrance-thanks for ansswer. how would you structure the array

Comment: Structure it how you want it used.

Comment: sorry. i meant that i am  seeking clarification by what you meant when you said to structure my array properly first? perhaps you are right and there is a better way to construct the array

Comment: @theSeeker Where you're building the original array, change it so the structure is what you want. Then you will not need this additional code to fix the structure.